# What's the difference between OuterClass.this and new OuterClass() while referencing an outer class from an anonymous inner class?

Tags: java, android, this, anonymous-inner-class

Actually in Android, while using intent to move to a different activity using OnClick Listener object I use the snippet

```
import android.widget.TextView;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    // Set the content of the activity to use the activity_main.xml layout file
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    TextView numbers = findViewById(R.id.numbers);
    numbers.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            startActivity(new Intent(**MainActivity.this**, NumbersActivity.class));
        }
    });


}

}
```

But even the snippet below works well

```
import android.widget.TextView;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    // Set the content of the activity to use the activity_main.xml layout file
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    TextView numbers = findViewById(R.id.numbers);
    numbers.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            startActivity(new Intent(**new MainActivity()**, NumbersActivity.class));
        }
    });


}

}
```

To highlight the difference I would like to mark the difference in **...**. Does this mean that while trying to access the Outer Class of the Anonymous Inner class we will have to access it using the snippet "OuterClass.this" inside the Inner class . But when I use "new OuterClass()" instead of "OuterClass.this" inside the anonymous inner class even this gives a correct result. I want to ask whether both the formats are same or they have any hidden difference as a consequence.

Comment: you cannot even compare this two situations ... java's basics `operator new` and `this` ... obviosuly `Intent` contructor expects to get any Context object as first parameters

Comment: but both of them give the same result

Comment: no, second should not wok as you should not create instance of Activity derrived class on android platform ... **also in first case you are passing the outer class instance as parameter and in second case you are passing new instance of the same class** ... you should learn some java's basic before starting android programming

Comment: very sorry ...It does not work...I got it...but both are returning objects of the outer class. The difference is that one is making an entirely new object but the other is referencing the current Outer class instance...please correct me If I am wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Those two operators are not comparable.

While using `new MainActivity()`, you are creating in memory a new object, identified as a `MainActivity`.

[Documentation for "new".](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/objectcreation.html)

While using `MainActivity.this`, you are refering to the object where you are, from the `MainActivity` class. It only works because you are *already* in a `MainActivity` class. Your compiler understands this, and MainActivity refers to itself. (Take me back if I'm wrong, I'm not sure about this whole textblock).

[Documentation for "this".](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/thiskey.html)

I would advise you using the **first** usage. The second one is tricky and you would not understand why it does not work, confusing you in your understanding of Java and (in a sense) object-oriented programming.

Comment: but actually, both are filling the place for the instance of the Outer class isn't? One is creating simply an entirely new object but the other is referencing and returning the current object...Please tell me If I'm thinking wrong?

Comment: Both are filling the place for the instance of the Outer class. The part about my advice is only my opinion, as Andy on another answer I'm no expert either. I would advise you checking about a guide on `Intent` on Android, or simply learn "plain" Java before going in those kind of cases.

Comment: Sir, I appreciate your advice...can you please help me by suggesting any resources about how to learn about efficiently about inner class, local classes, anonymous classes and other nested concepts...the oracle docs seem to very very overwhelming...Thanks a lot

Comment: There are a lot. When in doubt, the [Oracle official documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/index.html) is always helpful. If you like interacting coding, the [Codecademy](https://www.codecademy.com/learn/learn-java/) has some nice tutorials, in the form of assisted projects. [Java Lessons](http://javalessons.com) will teach you from examples (this is one of the best way), and if you feel ready to try things out in Java later on, I advise you to try some [Code katas](http://codekata.com/). And, of course, when in doubt, check first here on StackOverflow (good reflex :)).

Comment: It has been a great help...I appreciate it a lot

Comment: public class MyClass {
    int x = 0;
    public static void main(String args[]) {
        MyClass i = new MyClass();
        i.x=78;
        i.print();
       
    }
    public  void print(){
        System.out.println(new MyClass().x);
        System.out.print(this.x);
        
    }
    
    }
This code gives the result as:                                                                         0
78                                                                                                                  Probably it's self explanatory

Comment: Glad I helped. Be well on your coding journey.

Answer (score 0):

1. *new* creates a new instance (object), so `new MainActivity()` creates a new instance of *MainActivity*.
2. `MainActivity.this` refers to the already existing instance of *MainActivity*. This format is necessary, because you are accessing it from within the instance of `View.OnClickListener` where a plain `this` would reference this instance of `View.OnClickListener`.

So, I don't know Android that much, but I think what you want to do is to go with `MainActivity.this` because it refernces the already existing object of *MainActivity*.

Comment: this considerably helped me

Comment: @DeepRoy then I would kindly ask you to accept it as the answer.